# How to use trimage image compressor in a grunt responsive images task

Tags: gruntjs

I want to use trimage image compressor to compress images for my website . What do I need to provide to the engine option in my grunt responsive images task so that it can use trimage?

I have tried this on windows using image-magick with the `engine:"im"` in my grunt responsive images task and it works well, switching to ubuntu, I have installed trimage image compressor and set the `engine:"trimage"` but it generates an error `Warning: Invalid render engine specified Use --force to continue.`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    responsive_images: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          engine: "trimage",
          sizes: [
            {
              width: 300,
              suffix: "_sm",
              quality: 60
            },
            {
              width: 500,
              suffix: "_md",
              quality: 60
            }
          ]
        },

        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            src: ["*.{gif,jpg,png}"],
            cwd: "images_src/",
            dest: "img/"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    grunt.registerTask("default",["responsive_images"]);
};
```

Comment: `grunt-responsive-images` only supports `im` _(ImageMagick)_ or `gm` _(GraphicsMagick)_ rendering engines, as shown in the source code [here](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images/blob/305745fda1afd4fd55b51c2f64d3aef1fae53b7b/tasks/responsive_images.js#LC59). It's [`getEngine`](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images/blob/305745fda1afd4fd55b51c2f64d3aef1fae53b7b/tasks/responsive_images.js#LC83) function is not aware of `trimage` as it's not defined in the `GFX_ENGINES` object. You'd need to make edits to the source code itself to get it to work with `trimage`.

Comment: thanks @RobC this really makes sense.